# Two swagger endpoints inside a spring application

Tags: java, spring-boot, swagger

I'm using a springfox-swagger-ui 2.9.2 version and I'd like to have two swaggers that contain endpoints from different versions of an application like this:

`/api/v1/swagger-ui.html`

`/api/v2/swagger-ui.html`

Is there any ways to implement this?